# How to deploy asynchronously an application using REST in weblogic 12C?

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have been deploying a weblogic application using the REST api with the following snippet

```sh
    curl --insecure -X POST  --user ${userpass} -F\"deployment=@${appFileName}\" -F\"model={name: '${appName}',  deploymentOptions: { retireGracefully: 'false', timeout: '0' } , ${appType} ${appPlanVersion} targets: [ ${appTargets} ]}\" ${wlhost}/management/wls/latest/deployments/application "
```

I have to wait until this curl ends , but sometimes the request times out because of server configuration.

so, I thought it would be better to do this operation asynchronously, I have read in the documentation that I can use header

```sh
    -X Prefer:respond-async
```

but is not clear how to use it, I was not able to find an useful example, once I have added the header, the request is going to return a task URL like 
BODY:

```
    {
        "links": [{
            "rel": "job",
            "href": "http:\//localhost:7001/management/weblogic/latest/domainRuntime/deploymentManager/deploymentProgressObjects/fairShare"
        }],
        "operationType": 5,
        "state": "STATE_RUNNING",
        "applicationName": "fairShare",
        "progress": "processing",
        "completed": false
    }
```

how do I poll that job URL to know that the application was deployed and is active ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the request parameter _detached= true
in the post URL,
This will start the deployment asynchronously

for an example , refer to this document.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLRMR/management_wls_version_deployments_application.htm#WLRMR290

Answer (score 0):

If you'll execute:

> curl --insecure -X GET --user ${userpass} ${wlhost}/management/tenant-monitoring/applications/${appName}

when application ${appName} is not deployed, you should get 404 Not Found.

when it's deployed, you should get a JSON similar to this:

```
{
"body": {
    "item": {
        "name": "${appName}",
        "type": "ear",
        "state": "STATE_ACTIVE",
        "health": "HEALTH_WARN",
        "targetStates": [
            {
                "target": "wls",
                "state": "STATE_ACTIVE"
            }
        ],
        "dataSources": [],
        "workManagers": [
            {
                "pendingRequests": 0,
                "completedRequests": 125,
                "name": "default",
                "server": "wls"
            }
        ],
        "minThreadsConstraints": [],
        "maxThreadsConstraints": [],
        "requestClasses": []
    }
},
"messages": []
}
```

*Tested (in Postman) on WebLogic 12.2.1.4*